# Accessing the Function Name within the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not understanding how can I can access my function thumbs() where ever it is necessary in the same function.

Here is a demo link:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/60/

function thumbs(), this should be able to called where ever it is neccessary in the same function

Answer (score 0):

Is this that you are looking for ?

```
$('#tprev').click(function(e){
  thumbs(0,1);
});
```

I'm not sure what you want. I kinda presume you copied pasted some JS and are trying to excute the code.

What this does is pretty simple is says on the event click on the element which id is #tprev call this function with those parameters. I put 0 and 1 as pure guess. Could be what you want.

Comment: Can You please explain me what should this does?

Comment: This function should be access anywhere that I an able to access